# Deleting entities in Dynamics 4

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have about 40 entities in Dynamics that I need to delete. Some of them has relationships to each other. Deleting them using the web UI is very tedious as I have to make sure that there are no entities using the one I'm currently trying to delete. Is there a quick way to delete them (maybe directly in SQL Server)?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could automate this with a program using the CrmService and Metadata Service, but I'm pretty sure writing that is not quicker than deleting the entities by hand (though it would be an interesting thing to build with all the special steps that task would include).

Never do things like this directly through the database server; that's a sure-fire way to corrupt your database beyond repair.

Comment: That's definitely not the answer I was hoping for, but it is the answer I expected. I'll look into writing something. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a dev instance?  Start over and import what you do want ;)  Its could be a long, painful exercise fixing all those views, forms, etc.